# std::cout prevents a segfault in function?

Tags: c++, dictionary, segmentation-fault, cout

I'm using the finite element library for some calculations, and I've encountered a bizarre problem. 
I basically have the following for loop:

```
  MeshBase::const_node_iterator  node_it = mesh.nodes_begin();
  for (unsigned int i=0;i<n_nodes;i++ , node_it++){
    const Node* node2 = *node_it;
    Point dumpoint( (*node2)(0), (*node2)(1), (*node2)(2));
    Number dumreal= (Number) mesh_data.get_data(node2)[0];

//    std::cout << dumreal <<std::endl;
    dummap[dumpoint] = mesh_data.get_data(node2)[0];

  }
```

If I uncomment the line with cout, it works. Otherwise I get a segfault. It doesn't matter what I print:

```
std::cout << std::endl;
```

An important note is that dummap is a **global**

```
std::map<Point,Number>
```

Comment: You must have some out of bound access or some other undefined behaviour inducing problem elsewhere in the program.

Comment: juanchopanza is most probably right, try to use a debugger or profiler like valgrind.

Comment: Show the code for `operator[]` for your `dummap` - how does it do the indexing based on `Point`?

Comment: libmesh runs with openmpi, but it is single-threaded

Comment: Is n_nodes always less than the number of nodes between mesh.nodes_begin() and mesh.nodes_end()?

Comment: I've seen similar issues where using `cout` appeared to magically suppress an error.  It had to do with the fact that outputting to the console is simply a really slow process, so the loop was going much much slower than it normally would.  This might just be delaying the error, so it will show up, you just need to wait much longer.  Or in some cases, the program is structured in such a way that the timing prevents the error from showing up altogether.  If you replace the `cout` statement with a similarly slow process, I bet you will have similar results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using valgrind showed that the problem was with some char* array I allocated somewhere else. 
Thanks ^^